# Problema com background e linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou tentando fazer um background para o `body` usando uma imagem e um `linear-gradient`, no carregamento o gradiente aparece por um instante, mas logo é substituído apenas pela imagem, como podem ver abaixo.

```css
body {
    background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Lake_O_Hara_from_Yukness_Ledge_Alpine_Route.jpg/800px-Lake_O_Hara_from_Yukness_Ledge_Alpine_Route.jpg"),
    linear-gradient(to left, rgb(0,180,0), rgb(0,180,180));  
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Por quê isso acontece?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem dois problemas ai.

O primeiro, que não é exatamente um problema é que a imagem está por cima do `linear-gradiente`, e não o `linear-gradiente` que está por cima da imagem.

O segundo é que vc está usando `rgb()` e deveria ser `rgba()` no gradiente, assim vc consegue colocar a opacidade como quiser.

**Ex:** `rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`, o "A" é o canal Alpha e ele controla a transparecia da cor, no exemplo que dei é um preto com 50% de opacidade.

**Veja como ficou seu código depois do ajuste:**

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0,180,0,0.5), rgba(0,180,180,0.5)), url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Lake_O_Hara_from_Yukness_Ledge_Alpine_Route.jpg/800px-Lake_O_Hara_from_Yukness_Ledge_Alpine_Route.jpg");  
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado, porém agora surgiu outra dúvida por causa do `rgba`, vi em um exemplo assim, `body {
 background: url('imagens/capa.png'),
    url('imagens/ruido.png'),
    linear-gradient(50deg,#ff4169,#7c26f8);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}`, essa sobreposição é feita com o overflow? Pois as cores do `linear-gradient` estão em hexadecimal, e o gradiente esta em baixo da `url` da imagem.

Comment: Isso deve ser pq as imagens .PNG tb aceitam o Alpha Channel, ou seja vc tb pode por transparência nelas no editor de imagens tipo Photoshop, depois exporta o .PNG translucido, só pode ser isso, ou então o elemento está todo com transparência. Só avaliando o modelo para ter certeza. Sobre o overflow ele não serve para criar transparência, ele serve para "esconder" o que estiver saindo da Div, tipo se o conteúdo do Filho estiver saindo de dentro do Pai vc coloca overflow no Pai para esconder o conteúdo do Filho que está pra fora entende.

Comment: Nossa, é exatamente isso, estava tentando resolver tudo no `CSS`, eu tinha feito com `rgba`, mas a imagem `.jpg` estava em cima, então escondia o gradiente da mesma forma, muito obrigado @hugocsl pela excelente explicação!

Comment: Isso ai, Tmj []´s